# Roblox won't detect mouse movement from autopygui

Tags: python, roblox, pyautogui

I am trying to create a script that automatically rejoins a roblox game on disconnect. I have beeen using ctypes to obtain a pixel on the screen, and if the pixel matches a color, it should automatically press the rejoin button. the problem is that it wont press the button. After some troubleshooting, I have figured out that the mouse movement wont register with the game, as if I move my mouse manually, it clicks the button.

In short, the game won't detect mouse movement from autopygui. If I move my mouse manually, it registers.

Video example:
https://youtu.be/VvAfHHXul8Q

Code:

```
import pyautogui as py
import keyboard
import tkinter
import requests
from ctypes import windll
from time import sleep

key = "m"
toggled = False
rjcolor = 16777215

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.withdraw()

width, height = root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()

dc= windll.user32.GetDC(0)

def getpixel(x,y):
    return windll.gdi32.GetPixel(dc,x,y)

while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed(key):
        toggled = not toggled
        print("toggled to " + str(toggled))
        sleep(0.5)
    if toggled == True:
        py.moveTo(width / 2, 800)
        py.click(button='left')
        if getpixel(1050, 600) == rjcolor:
            print("disconnected, waiting until internet back online!")
            while True:
                try:
                    requests.head("http://www.google.com/", timeout=3)
                    print('The internet connection is active, rejoining.')
                    py.moveTo(1050, 590)
                    py.mouseDown(button='left')
                    sleep(0.1)
                    py.mouseUp(button='left')
                    break
                    
                except requests.ConnectionError:
                    print("The internet connection is down")
                sleep(3)
    sleep(0.1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Pyautogui has issues with clicking on roblox, but i've found a workaround:

Replace `py.click(button="left")` with `autoit.mouse_click("left")`

```
     import autoit
     autoit.mouse_click("left")
```

Comment: did not work for me, same issue.